# Android: How to populate listview with multi dimensional array of different types?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have two `Arraylists` one from a class `ArrayList<ClassName>` and another of `ArrayList<String>` both are of different size. How can populate in two a single list view.

`ArrayList<String>` contains time as string for example say "09:00 - 09:30" and `ArrayList<ClassName>` contains bookings done for the particular time.

So final output of the list should be like this:

> 09:00 - 09:30 Booked by User 1 for date 31/07/2014
>   09:30 - 10:00  Available
>   10:00 - 10:30  Available
>   10:30 - 11:00  Available

Here `ArrayList<String>` is having size of 4 and `ArrayList<Classname>` is having size of 1. So how I can arrive on this solution. Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create generic class, for example `RowItem`, with incapsulated data.

```
List<RowItem> rowList = RowItem.create(ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<Classname>);
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_item, rowList);
```

`RowItem` class would have such public methods:

```
class RowItem {

     ...

    public String getTime() {
        ...
    }

    public String getAvailability() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I bind itemsAdapter to list and what would class ``Row`` extend? Can you please elaborate it.